# How to retrieve percentage type value from excel sheet using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read cell values excel sheet using Apache POI. One of my sheet contains percentage type as the cell type. When I read that cell using POI using cell.getNumbericValue(), its returning me the double value. If cell contains 11.24%, it is returning me 0.1124. 
My problem is, I want to read the % symbol also from the cell i.e., I want to read the exact data as it is in cell as 11.24%. So, I tried it using the cell.toString(), even then it is returning me the same value as above. 
Can anyone please suggest me, how to get rid of this problem.
Thanks in advance
Nandu

Comment: That's the value you'll get. Excel gives it a format to present it but the data is what you get. Perform some check to know if the cell has a particular type of data

Answer (score 16):

You can detect if a cell is formatted as a percentage by testing the cell data format string like this:

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
    if (cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString().contains("%")) {
        // Detect Percent Values 
        Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue() * 100;
        System.out.println("Percent value found = " + value.toString() +"%");
    } else {
        Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        System.out.println("Non percent value found = " + value.toString());
    }
}
```

This should enable you to distinguish between percentage formatted values and ordinary numeric values.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String typeCell =cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
```

It gives:

- "General" value for non formated cells,
- "0%" for percentage formats
- dd/mm/yy for date , depends of locale

I manage to parse all types in cells (Numbers, Percentage, Date, Text, Currency) I just have to check what value for which cell type it will give me back.
Because I also have to much trouble with `HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING` or `HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`.

Answer (score 1):

11.24% is 0.1124, which is why that's what gets stored in the file, and that's what you get when you ask for the numeric value

POI provides a utility for formatting numeric strings based on the format rules applied to the cell, which is [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). If you use that to format the cell, you'll get back a string with the contents of the cell largely as seen in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @WeeShetland should be the accepted answer.

Instead of `cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString().contains("%")` you can use

```
// class level
private static final int PERCENTAGE_FORMAT = BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat("0%");

...


// in some method
if (cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat() == PERCENTAGE_FORMAT) {
    ...
```